# how to convert an activity into a fragment to be used in tab layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

here is an activity i was trying to convert to a fragment, so i could use it in a sliding tab layout as a fragment.

```
package com.example.hpuser.speechtotext;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView resultTEXT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
});
resultTEXT= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVresult);
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton) {
promptSpeechInput();     
}
}

public void promptSpeechInput() {
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,        
RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something!");

try {
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException a)
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry! your device does not support       
speech Language!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}

public void onActivityResult(int request_code, int result_code, Intent i) {
super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, i);

switch(request_code)
{
case 100: if(result_code == RESULT_OK && i != null)
{
ArrayList<String> result =    
i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
       resultTEXT.setText(result.get(0));

            }
                break;
        }


}
```

here is the actual fragment of the activity i was coding up. the app is crashing though, any help?

```
package com.example.vez.design3;
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
TextView resultTEXT;

private  LinearLayout llLayout;
private  FragmentActivity faActivity;
public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
faActivity = (FragmentActivity) super.getActivity();
llLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,  
container, false);

resultTEXT = (TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.TVresult);

return llLayout;

}


public void promptSpeechInput() {
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,  
RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something!");

try {
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException a)
{
Toast.makeText(super.getActivity(), "Sorry! your device does not   
support speech Language!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}

public void onActivityResult(int request_code, int result_code, Intent i) {
super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, i);

switch(request_code)
{
case 100: if(result_code == 1 && i != null)
{
ArrayList<String> result =    
i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
resultTEXT.setText(result.get(0));

}
break;
}


}



}
```

Comment: what's in crash logs??

Comment: @VivekMishra, it just says app stops reponding, but what i found out is that when i comment out resultTEXT = (TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.TVresult);   it loads up good but i need these widgets to work however

Comment: it also works fine when i have this in OncreateView but how do i load up id of the widgets using view.findViewById()?
`code`  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        
    } `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of this**

`private  LinearLayout llLayout;`  and `llLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container, false);`

**Try This**

```
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null, false);
    resultTEXT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TVresult);
    return view;
```